# Problem with table formatting

Tags: tables

I would like to know what is wrong with this code above:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Título} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Story Points} & \textbf{Responsável} \\
1 & Elaborar a Introdução do Projeto & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
2 & Elaborar a Problematização, Solução Proposta e Justificativa & Atividade & 5 & Milton \\
5 & Estruturar Trabalho no Google Docs & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
7 & Ata da Reunião \#4 & Atividade & 1 & Murilo \\
8 & Publicações no Blog (Aula 21/08 e Reunião \#4) & Atividade & 1 & Caique \\
9 & Revisão da Proposta Inicial & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
12 & Elaboração do Burndown Chart & Atividade & 5 & Caique \\
15 & Setup do Ambiente & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
17 & Estudar Plug-ins de Análise Estática & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
20 & Pesquisar e Desenvolver Tutorial de JUnit & Atividade & 8 & Arion \\
21 & Desenvolver Esqueleto do Projeto no Spring Boot & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
24 & Integrar STS ao Code Convention do Google (GitHub) & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
25 & Elaborar os RFs, RNFs e RNs & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
26 & Elaborar o DFD 0 & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
27 & Elaborar o DFD 1 & Atividade & 5 & Arion \\
28 & Elaborar o Caso de Uso Geral & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
29 & Elaborar Modelagem de Dados & Atividade & 5 & Murilo \\
30 & Elaborar Identidade Visual da Aplicação & Atividade & 8 & Caique \\
32 & Recriar Vídeo de Apresentação & Atividade & 3 & Adriana \\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{Total de Pontos}} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textbf{69}}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This code is generating a table like this one. The table doesn't fit correctly:

[image: The table doesn't fit wel...]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snipped to complete but small document beginning with`\documentclas{...}` and ending with `end{document}. it seems that your table is to wide for your text width ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabularx` to have columns with an automatic linebreak. Loading `makecell` allows to have a common formatting and line breaks for column heads. I also took the liberty to modify some alignments so the corresponding columns look better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut, makecell,booktabs, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rXccl}
\thead{ID} & \thead{Título} & \thead{Tipo} & \thead{Story\\ Points} & \thead{Responsável} \\
1 & Elaborar a Introdução do Projeto & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
2 & Elaborar a Problematização, Solução Proposta e Justificativa & Atividade & 5 & Milton \\
5 & Estruturar Trabalho no Google Docs & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
7 & Ata da Reunião \#4 & Atividade & 1 & Murilo \\
8 & Publicações no Blog (Aula 21/08 e Reunião \#4) & Atividade & 1 & Caique \\
9 & Revisão da Proposta Inicial & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
12 & Elaboração do Burndown Chart & Atividade & 5 & Caique \\
15 & Setup do Ambiente & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
17 & Estudar Plug-ins de Análise Estática & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
20 & Pesquisar e Desenvolver Tutorial de JUnit & Atividade & 8 & Arion \\
21 & Desenvolver Esqueleto do Projeto no Spring Boot & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
24 & Integrar STS ao Code Convention do Google (GitHub) & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
25 & Elaborar os RFs, RNFs e RNs & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
26 & Elaborar o DFD 0 & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
27 & Elaborar o DFD 1 & Atividade & 5 & Arion \\
28 & Elaborar o Caso de Uso Geral & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
29 & Elaborar Modelagem de Dados & Atividade & 5 & Murilo \\
30 & Elaborar Identidade Visual da Aplicação & Atividade & 8 & Caique \\
32 & Recriar Vídeo de Apresentação & Atividade & 3 & Adriana \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{Total de Pontos}} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textbf{69}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This approach use `tabulary` for automatic linebreaks and  `array` to center headers and allow some space between rows. The font is reduced to   the the standard `\footnotesize`. I do not recommend scaling the tables as first alternative because the lack of consistency with the font size of other parts of the document. A document where each table has a different font size is simply appalling.

[image: mwe]

However, nothing of this can make miracles with poor designs. Almost always some change in the content is acceptable and allow fit the table much better: Is the column "Type" really necessary if it never changed? And "Story Points" instead of simply "Points"? etc.  Only you can said that, but if not, it could look better:

[image: mwe2]

```
\documentclass{article} % Atenção: compilá-lo com xelatex ou lualatex 
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\footnotesize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{lLlm{3em}l}\toprule
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Título} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Story Points} & \textbf{Responsável} \\
\midrule
1 & Elaborar a Introdução do Projeto & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
2 & Elaborar a Problematização, Solução Proposta e Justificativa & Atividade & 5 & Milton \\
5 & Estruturar Trabalho no Google Docs & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
7 & Ata da Reunião \#4 & Atividade & 1 & Murilo \\
8 & Publicações no Blog (Aula 21/08 e Reunião \#4) & Atividade & 1 & Caique \\
9 & Revisão da Proposta Inicial & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
12 & Elaboração do Burndown Chart & Atividade & 5 & Caique \\
15 & Setup do Ambiente & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
17 & Estudar Plug-ins de Análise Estática & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
20 & Pesquisar e Desenvolver Tutorial de JUnit & Atividade & 8 & Arion \\
21 & Desenvolver Esqueleto do Projeto no Spring Boot & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
24 & Integrar STS ao Code Convention do Google (GitHub) & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
25 & Elaborar os RFs, RNFs e RNs & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
26 & Elaborar o DFD 0 & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
27 & Elaborar o DFD 1 & Atividade & 5 & Arion \\
28 & Elaborar o Caso de Uso Geral & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
29 & Elaborar Modelagem de Dados & Atividade & 5 & Murilo \\
30 & Elaborar Identidade Visual da Aplicação & Atividade & 8 & Caique \\
32 & Recriar Vídeo de Apresentação & Atividade & 3 & Adriana \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\textbf{Total de Pontos}} & \textbf{69} \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\footnotesize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{lLm{3em}l}\toprule
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Título} &  \textbf{Story Points} & \textbf{Responsável} \\
\midrule
1 & Elaborar a Introdução do Projeto  & 2 & Murilo \\
2 & Elaborar a Problematização, Proposta e Solução  & 5 & Milton \\
5 & Estruturar Trabalho no Google Docs   & 2 & Murilo \\
7 & Ata da Reunião \#4   & 1 & Murilo \\
8 & Publicações no Blog (Aula 21/08 e Reunião \#4)   & 1 & Caique \\
9 & Revisão da Proposta Inicial   & 2 & Murilo \\
12 & Elaboração do Burndown Chart   & 5 & Caique \\
15 & Setup do Ambiente   & 2 & Adriana \\
17 & Estudar Plug-ins de Análise Estática   & 2 & Adriana \\
20 & Pesquisar e Desenvolver Tutorial de JUnit   & 8 & Arion \\
21 & Desenvolver Esqueleto do Projeto no Spring Boot   & 2 & Adriana \\
24 & Integrar STS ao Code Convention do Google (GitHub)   & 3 & Milton \\
25 & Elaborar os RFs, RNFs e RNs   & 5 & Ivan \\
26 & Elaborar o DFD 0   & 5 & Ivan \\
27 & Elaborar o DFD 1   & 5 & Arion \\
28 & Elaborar o Caso de Uso Geral   & 3 & Milton \\
29 & Elaborar Modelagem de Dados   & 5 & Murilo \\
30 & Elaborar Identidade Visual da Aplicação   & 8 & Caique \\
32 & Recriar Vídeo de Apresentação   & 3 & Adriana \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{Total de Pontos}} & \textbf{69} \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fit your table to the page width, one simple way is to use `scalebox{}{}` as follows:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Título} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Story Points} & \textbf{Responsável} \\
1 & Elaborar a Introdução do Projeto & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
2 & Elaborar a Problematização, Solução Proposta e Justificativa & Atividade & 5 & Milton \\
5 & Estruturar Trabalho no Google Docs & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
7 & Ata da Reunião \#4 & Atividade & 1 & Murilo \\
8 & Publicações no Blog (Aula 21/08 e Reunião \#4) & Atividade & 1 & Caique \\
9 & Revisão da Proposta Inicial & Atividade & 2 & Murilo \\
12 & Elaboração do Burndown Chart & Atividade & 5 & Caique \\
15 & Setup do Ambiente & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
17 & Estudar Plug-ins de Análise Estática & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
20 & Pesquisar e Desenvolver Tutorial de JUnit & Atividade & 8 & Arion \\
21 & Desenvolver Esqueleto do Projeto no Spring Boot & Atividade & 2 & Adriana \\
24 & Integrar STS ao Code Convention do Google (GitHub) & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
25 & Elaborar os RFs, RNFs e RNs & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
26 & Elaborar o DFD 0 & Atividade & 5 & Ivan \\
27 & Elaborar o DFD 1 & Atividade & 5 & Arion \\
28 & Elaborar o Caso de Uso Geral & Atividade & 3 & Milton \\
29 & Elaborar Modelagem de Dados & Atividade & 5 & Murilo \\
30 & Elaborar Identidade Visual da Aplicação & Atividade & 8 & Caique \\
32 & Recriar Vídeo de Apresentação & Atividade & 3 & Adriana \\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{Total de Pontos}} & \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textbf{69}}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

The following images demonstrates`0.8` and `0.5` scales of your original table:

[image]

However, using `scalebox` has severe drawbacks, such as running the risk of making the table undecipherable because the font is effectively too small.  Linear shrinking should be contemplated only as a last-resort, not as the first step.